# How to add a custom component from encodebegin?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component, dynamically-generated

I've created a custom component which extends the `UIComponentBase` abstract class, so when I use this component: `<test:mycomponent />` It works as espected.

I'm creating another custom component and I want to use the previously created component in this one, so I tried:

```
@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

    writer.startElement("mycomponent", this);

    writer.endElement("mycomponent");                        
}
```

I new this was a long shot, since `startElement` just creates a tag with the given component name i.e `mycomponent`,  so I searched around and found:

> UIComponentBase mycomponent =
>   (UIComponentBase)context.getApplication().createComponent("mycomponent");

If this is correct, how does one add the component ?  I'm using JSF 2.2
A link to where I can find more on this would be greatly apreciated also.

Comment: It has to happen during view build time not view render time. Lookup taghandlers. Or, look for a different solution for the problem you had in mind. This all is strange. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000/

Comment: @BalusC, So I can't reuse a custom component to create a new one ?